# Why can't I set a List<Y> to a variable of type List<X> where the Y extends X in Java?

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

So, I got two classes, let's call them X and Y, where Y extends X, and I have a method that receives a List.

When I try to pass a List to it, the Eclipse IDE warns that i can't do that and if I try an overloading to create another signature to receive a List, it then warns me that the signature already exists (the one that receives List), and I suppose that it's because Y extends X

Am i misunderstanding something in OO, is something wrong about my classes or the compiler/IDE is crazy?

Some code example bellow:

```
public class X {
    // X class things
}

public class Y extends X {
    // Y class things
}

public void doSomethingWithTheList(List<X> list) {
    // method implementation
}

...

// First case, where I tried to set the List<Y> into a variable of type List<X>
List<X> xList = getXList();
List<X> yList = getYList();  // compiler/IDE warns me that I can't do it

...

// Second case, where I tried to pass a List<Y> into the method that receives List<X>
List<X> xList = getXList();
List<Y> yList = getYList();

doSomethingWithTheList(xList);  // Works fine
doSomethingWithTheList(yList);  // compiler/Eclipse warns me that I can't do it
```

*Note: getXList() returns the type List and getYList() returns the type List in both cases*

What can I be doing wrong here?

Comment: SImply because `Y extends X` does not imply `GenericType<Y> extends GenericType<X>` in Java. But ... it implies `GenericType<Y> extends GenericType<? extends X>`.

Answer (score 3):

You should read up more on generics. In general a `List<X>` is different from a `List<Y>`.

Consider the following (non-compiling) example: `List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();` - If this would work, I could now add a `Double` to `list` because it also extends `Number` but the actual list is meant to only contain `Integer` instances.

In your case `List<Y>` means the list should only contain `Y` instances but `List<X>` would allow you to also add  `X` instances or others that also extend/implement `X`.

Try `List<? extends X> yList = getYList();`. This should work and you could read the elements of `yList` and treat them as instances of `X`. But the compiler wouldn't allow you to add elements to `yList` because it can't be sure the elements match the original generic boundary of the list.

To summarize:

```
//defining exact boundaries
List<X> xList = getXList(); //works as you get a List<X>
List<X> yList = getYList();  //doesn't work as the generic boundaries don't match

//defining upper bounds, i.e. X or any subclass
List<? extends X> atLeastXList = getYList();  //works, as the boundaries state X or subclasses
X first = atLeastXList.get(0); //works, as the boundaries state elements are at least of type X
Y second = atLeastXList.get(1); //doesn't work as the compiler only knows the elements have at least type X

atLeastXList.add(new X()); //doesn't work as the compiler can't be sure this would be allowed (it wouldn't as the list would actually be a List<Y> in your case)

//defining lower bounds, i.e. X or any super class
List<? super X> atMostXList = getXList();  //works, as X is the lower boundary
List<? super X> brokenAtLeastXList = getYList();  //doesn't work as Y is not a super class of X 

atMostXList.add(new X()); //works as any matching list will allow instances off X (e.g. it could actually be a List<Object> which be fine too)
atMostXList.add(new Y()); //works as Y extends X
atMostXList.add(new Object()); //doesn't work as the list could actually require only X instances to be added
```

For more information, look up the [PECS rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: Instead of using "List<? extends X> atLeastXList = getYList();", I let it be just List<Y> but added the "List<? extends X>" to the method itself and it work. Thanks for the clarifications

Comment: @RafaelFurtado I'm not sure I understand you correctly but doing `List<X> = getYList()` with a return type of `List<? extends X>` should not work for the reasons I stated above. If it does it is a bug in the compiler -  if you made if work by some casting you shouldn't do that unless you really need it and know what you're doing.

Comment: I mean the method that will receive the lists: public void doSomethingWithTheList(List<? extends X> list)

Comment: @RafaelFurtado ah, I see. Yes, that's a valid approach.